# Create a new temporary local table from the result set data from a SELECT statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT o_id,first_name,last_name
INTO newoperator
FROM operators
WHERE o_id >5 GROUP BY first_name
```

> syntax error at or near "INTO"

Can anyone help

Comment: is this `sql-server` or `postgresql` ?

Comment: probably not postgresql, because of `ERROR:  column "operators.o_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: In Postgres you need to use `create temporary table newoperatory as select ...` - but the `group by` usage is invalid SQL  and will be rejected by any self-respecting DBMS

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please add only one tag for the BMS product you are really using

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are trying to accomplish is creating a table based on another table.  The generic term for this in SQL is CTAS -- which stands for `CREATE TABLE AS`.

Not all databases support this syntax.  For instance, SQL Server uses the `SELECT INTO` syntax.

That is because that is the syntax most commonly used for this across databases:

```
CREATE TABLE newoperator AS
    SELECT DISTINCT o_id, first_name, last_name
    FROM operators
    WHERE o_id > 5;
```

Note that I fixed the query so it has some hope of working.  In your version, `last_name` and `o_id` were not in the `GROUP BY`, which would generate an error (in almost any database).